# Need help to construct a ring isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_3[\sqrt2]$ $\rightarrow $ $\mathbb{Z}_3[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I've looked at this problem for some time now and am confused as to where to start. I know that to prove these rings are isomorphic I must to construct a bijective function $\phi$ such that:

$\phi(a + b)$ = $\phi(a) + \phi(b)$

and

$\phi(ab)$ = $\phi(a)\phi(b)$.

I'm not exactly sure where to begin. If anyone could give some insight on where to begin or something to think about I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: think about what $\phi(\sqrt{2})$ can be

Comment: How about $\sqrt{2} \to i$ as a starter.

Comment: What od s$\sqrt 2^2$ and what is $i^2$ and what is the difference between these, if any?

Comment: Hint: $\bmod 3\!:\ \,2 \equiv-1\ $ so $\ \sqrt 2 \equiv \sqrt {-1}\ \ $

Comment: Be careful of ambiguous notations: for you, $\Bbb Z_3$ is evidently $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z=\Bbb F_3$; for many others, $\Bbb Z_3$ is the integers in the three-adic field $\Bbb Q_3$.

Comment: @Lubin fyi: nowadays (due to many *applications* of finite fields) that notation is probably more widely used for finite fields than it is for adics. There is little chance for confusion (beginners have no knowledge of adics, and those who do will likely have little difficulty resolving the ambiguity).

Comment: Right you are, @BillDubuque. It’s just because I’ve been trapped in the mire of the $p$-adic swamp for so long that I jumped to a false conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each ring has nine elements.  Clearly you need to send $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$, which forces you to send $2$ to $2$ to maintain addition.  Now $\sqrt 2$ has to go somewhere.  As $\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 2=2$ you need it to go somewhere that squares to $2=-1$.  Addition and multiplication will then fill out the function.

Comment: So would a potential answer look like this?

Define $\phi(\sqrt2) = i$? 

I'm confused as to how I should be writing this down.

Thank you for your answer by the way.

Comment: I would list the entire function $\phi$, which you can derive from $\phi(\sqrt 2)=i$ and include some description of how I got it and ruled out other possibilities.  For example, another possibility is that $\phi(\sqrt 2)=1+i$, but then you would have to have $\phi(2)=(1+i)^2=2i$ which contradicts our previous discovery that $\phi(2)=2$.  You need to do this to show the isomorphism is unique.  It depends on what your teacher expects.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to prove at all. Here $\sqrt{2}$ can only be interpreted as an element $u$ in some field extension of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ such that $u^2=2$; similarly, $i$ is an element in some field extension such that $i^2=-1=2$. Since both elements are roots of $x^2-2=0$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_3$, the two fields are obviously isomorphic and an isomorphism is obtained by
$$
a+b\sqrt{2}\mapsto a+bi
$$
If you use a common extension field, such as the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}_3$, then the two fields are actually equal, because $\sqrt{2}=i$ or $\sqrt{2}=-i$, both being roots of the same polynomial.

The complex numbers $\sqrt{2}$ and $i$ have ***nothing*** to do with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

ADDED: It occurred to me that things might have a more pleasant look if I used separate variables, one quotient $F[x] / (x^2 + 1)$ and the other $F[t] / (t^2 -2),$ where  $F = \mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z.$  Then the isomorphism has a concrete appearance,
$$  ax+b \mapsto at+b  $$

ORIGINAL:Well, $x^2 + 1 \equiv x^2 - 2 \pmod 3,$ which is promising.

Writing as $F[x] / (x^2 + n)$ for some $n$ we are writing  elements as $ax+b$ with $a,b \in F = \mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z.$

With $x^2 + 1,$ we get multiplication
$$ (ax+b)(cx+d) = (ad+bc)x + (bd-ac)    $$

With $x^2 -2,$ we get multiplication
$$ (ax+b)(cx+d) = (ad+bc)x + (bd+2ac)    $$

These look slightly different, but in $a,b,c,d \in F,$ we always have
 $$ -ac = 2ac  $$
because
$$ -ac \equiv 2ac \pmod 3  $$